# How to set a Telegram Bot to only respond to a specific user's messages?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have just created a bot with BotFather on Telegram. When a specific user messages it (i,e, me!), it triggers a some other software (Pabbly Connect) to fire some automation.

How can I ensure that my bot will only respond to messages from my specific account, and not from other Telegram users who message it?

Please note that my coding skills are weak, so if you have a solution, please would you spell it out for me!

Comment: Check the documentation of the library you are using.

Comment: You need to extract the username of that user whenever you receive a message from that particular Guy in Telegram. But you need to use some framework in order to do this. Selenium Python.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.